# Display flex and line-clamp

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have problem with line-clamp on Chrome.

When I use `display:-webkit-box` everything works fine but when i put display: flex (which is newest version of display: box) that it doesn't

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONoyPo)

Comment: Please add the code necessary to reproduce your problem within your question. Written like this it is totally unclear what you mean and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Per [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp)

This is a

> **Proprietary and undocumented** CSS property that will contain text to a given amount of lines when used in combination with display: -webkit-box. It will end with ellipsis when text-overflow: ellipsis is included.

My emphasis.

Additionally...

> As there is no specification and the property is dependent on an outdated implementation of flexbox (hence display: -webkit-box) it is unlikely that other browsers will support the property as-is, although an alternative solution may at some point replace it.